# Не понимаю, почему не матчится std::regex в g++ 4.8.2

Tags: c++, регулярные-выражения, gcc

Исходник:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  const std::string line("[27/Apr/2015:06:53:30 -0400] GET file.txt HTTP/1.1 206");
  const std::regex re("GET (.+) HTTP");
  std::cout << "Line: " << line << std::endl;
  std::smatch match;
  if(std::regex_search(line, match, re)) {
    std::cout << "Match: " << match[1] << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Компилируем:

```
g++ -Wall -std=c++1y -O2 parse.cpp -o parse
```

Строчка не матчится. Я почти уверен что все делаю правильно. Помогите понять, где я дурак.

Comment: Похоже, не поддерживает пока регэкспы gcc. В clang работает - clang++-3.5 -Wall -std=c++1y -stdlib=libc++ -O2 parse.cpp -o parse

Comment: Хм. На ideone работает (http://ideone.com/8mYe7w). Там тоже gcc, но версия 4.9.2. Может, обновите версию?

Comment: `std::regex` забагован даже в 4.9.2. Точнее, не сам `std::regex`, а его шаблон - `std::basic_regex<T>`. Якобы обобщённая реализация в одном из методов завязана строго на `char` в качестве типа символов, из которых состоят строки. Использовать сам `std::regex` это не мешает, и в 4.9.2 он вроде бы работает, но есть ощущение, что никто всерьёз эту фичу не тестировал.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что проблема не воспроизводится в свежих версиях **gcc**, поэтому любой ответ решающий проблему для данной версии gcc будет костылем для хромой кобылы, которая сдохла.

Answer (score 1):

gcc 5.1.0:

> Line: [27/Apr/2015:06:53:30 -0400] GET file.txt HTTP/1.1 206
>
> Match: file.txt

В районе gcc 4.8 - 4.9 была куча исправлений в regex от Tim Shen,
и теперь по крайней мере в gcc 5.1.0 он проходит все основные тесты.